# How to get through CORS policy to load fonts?

Tags: .htaccess, fonts, cors, cross-domain, font-face

To get access to my font i use @font-face.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque Regular';
    src: url('http://server/font/brandon_reg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://server/font/brandon_reg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://server/font/brandon_reg-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('http://server/font/brandon_reg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://server/font/brandon_reg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://server/font/brandon_reg-webfont.svg#brandon_grotesque_regularRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Unfortunetly i'm not able to get access to my fonts, my request has been blocked by CORS policy.

> Access to Font at
>   'http://server/font/brandon_blk-webfont.woff2'
>   from origin 'http://server.fr' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

So I edit a .htaccess

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ .ttf
AddType font/ .eot
AddType font/ .otf
AddType font/ .woff
AddType font/ .woff2
<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

It didn't work either. Any ideas ?

Comment: a few things: it's 2016, don't use the "load every format of webfont" approach anymore, [it's not necessary](/questions/37086562/#37091681). Secondly, why the `mod_headers.c` check? You know your server setup: `Header set` will work if you have mod_headers, so if it doesn't work, are you certain you haven't disabled mod_headers in the apache conf? Step 1 would be to remove everything except WOFF, simplify your `FilesMatch`, and remove the `IfModule`. Then see what happens.

Comment: You were right, my mode_headers was disabled.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
<FilesMatch ".(otf|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+.)?(localhost|yourdomain.com)$" origin_is=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
</FilesMatch>
```

put this in .htaccess file on your server, where fonts are placed

Comment: Can you explain what each line does? Is the 'e' intentional in `%{origin_is}e`?