# Fonts are loaded only for one language

Tags: css, font-face

**This was solved in my answer below**

I have a website in 2 languages.

German version: website/index.html
English version: website/english/index.html

The site loads Google fonts locally. Font file location: website/assets/fonts

This works for the german version, but not for the English one.

German main CSS file: website/assets/mbr/mbr-additional.css
English main CSS file: website/english/assets/mbr/mbr-additional.css

website/index.html loads this stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">
```

website/english/index.html also loads:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">
```

I import the font-face settings from the tangerine.css file. The fonts are located in the same folder as the tangerine.css file.

I import the tangerine.css file with this line:

```
@import url(https://websitename/assets/fonts/tangerine.css);
```

In the tangerine.css file, I have the following code (just one example for one browser):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Tangerine';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/tangerine-v17-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
```

Whenever I try and add the same code for the tangerine.css in the English mbr-additional.css the whole website changes the font to default and ignores everything else.

I tried renaming the fonts files, even duplicating the whole fonts folder in the English directory, and changing the @import code but it don't work.

I also tried `url('../../fonts/tangerine-v17-latin-regular.eot');` for the font, so the English mbr-additional.css uses the same files as the German one.

**Edit 1**: the devtools error shows a CORS error and is not allowing the fonts to load.

This is the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2)$">
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>

# Require all granted
Satisfy Any
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all

<FilesMatch "^\.">
    # Require all denied
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

I added the `<FilesMatch "\.(eot|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|woff2)$"> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" </FilesMatch>` but it still denies the request.

**Edit 2:**
I added this to the htaccess:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject    .eot
AddType application/x-font-opentype      .otf
AddType image/svg+xml                    .svg
AddType application/x-font-ttf           .ttf
AddType application/font-woff            .woff
AddType application/font-woff2           .woff2
```

**Edit 3:**

mbr-additional.css:

```
@import url(websitename/assets/fonts/roboto.css);
@import url(websitename/assets/fonts/roboto-condensed.css);
@import url(websitename/assets/fonts/tangerine.css);
@import url(websitename/assets/fonts/titillium.css);


body {
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
*and more css*
```

roboto font file (named roboto.css located in https://websitename/assets/fonts/):

```
/* roboto-100 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/roboto-v30-latin-100.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

The index.html(main page) calls the mbr-additional.css with :
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">`

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO, any errors in the browser dev tools. The css/assets section of your post is a bit messy. Can you share more HTML and CSS? Is your code on GitHub?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please also take a moment to read the instructions on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please review my edit, I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Christian your edit makes(so much more) sense, thanks a lot!
From the dev tools it looks like the CORS is blocking the correct loading of the font.
Here is an example:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
www.websitename/:1 Access to font at 'https://websitename/assets/fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.ttf' from origin 'https://websitename' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
The same error is not showing on the german website, only the english one.

Comment: I added this in the htacces,  but it still shows me the same CORS error on the english page.

<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

based on this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425464/how-to-get-through-cors-policy-to-load-fonts

Comment: If you get a CORS error, there must be different origins involved - but it is not clear from your description so far, where the origin could change to anything else here. Please quote the actual error message.

Answer (score 1):

Your server shows `Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. ([learn more](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default/#:%7E:text=strict%2Dorigin%2Dwhen%2Dcross%2Dorigin%20offers%20more%20privacy,the%20path%20and%20query%20string.))

The header does not contain the expected `access-control-allow-origin: *` header. The response header also contains the info `Server: Apache`.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197751/fonts-are-blocked-in-web-client-cors), I found a helpful website to get the right CORS configuration. Here's the Apache page: https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html, which says:

> To add the CORS authorization to the header using Apache, simply add the following line inside either the `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>` or `<VirtualHost>` sections of your server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file:
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_headers.c>
>  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
> </IfModule>
> ```

You can maybe even skip the `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` check

Comment: Thanks @Christian for this. I was already trying variations of this in the htaccess file, without any change.
Turns out, I had to add a line to the apache server settings in plesk, but an "older" one it seems. I wrote a detailed Information on this as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Every edit I did on the htaccess with the header settings was not accepted.

I solved the CORS problem by adding

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example1.com
```

to the Plesk Apache settings.

This Article [How to set up CORS - cross-origin resource sharing - in Plesk for Linux?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001338265-How-to-set-up-CORS-cross-origin-resource-sharing-in-Plesk-for-Linux-) was on the right track, but the code didn't work for me.

One user had the same problem and that's what solved it, here is their answer:

> In Plesk Obsidian we've been able to enable CORS for both >Apache and nginx (as long as Proxy mode is enabled, so not >for nginx standalone) by setting additional headers in the >Common Apache settings section, with this format:
> `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: example1.com`

Thanks everybody for you tremendous help!